# Specifying Font for iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, uifont, retina-display

I have the retina specifications for fonts on an app. If I divide them by 2, I get the non-retina font sizes. Should I provide the app with the non-retina sizes, and it will automatically scale it for retina? Or do I need to provide both?

Thanks,

Comment: Be more specific. Are you creating a TrueType font file? Generating static image files? Writing code to draw text to the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all the fonts in iOS is TrueType and will auto fit in both low resolution and retina display.

You should always use the unit of points to measure the UI elements (e.g. font size). And iOS would scale 1 point to 2 pixels in retina display.

Answer (score 2):

As a rule, you're specifying all positioning and sizing on Retina devices in non-Retina values. The OS handles the scaling of the fonts automatically for you, so you don't need to worry about it.